# Does Google Yolo / Google One-tap auth method alive now?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-authentication

I am trying to use google one-tap sign out method in my site. I Have read some of articles about this in Medium, but all of them are too old(2018). 
And as I see now - official documentation for this feature are gone - https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/

And I dont know, does google support google yolo now?

Answer (score 1):

It's public available now at: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web.

Answer (score 0):

I think Google Yolo might officially be dead

https://neerajsinha.com/google-one-tap-yolo/

Comment: Sounds sad( 
But if google yolo is dead, what happened with platforms, that already implement them? Medium, for example.