# Is GoogleYolo / Google one Tap Working again?

Tags: authentication, google-apps, status, yolo

So I read some old [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58503503/does-google-yolo-google-one-tap-auth-method-alive-now) here about Google deactivating the Google Yolo/One tap option (that was at the end of 2019). I'm not sure what's the status now since the [documentation](https://developers.google.cn/identity/one-tap/web) seems to work again.
Anybody has any idea about the current status of the feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The project seems to be active again and here are some recent [release notes](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/reference/release-notes).
I have tried it and it seems to work pretty well.

PS: Please check the browser support and know your user base if you plan to use that as your only authentication mechanism though. Always have a fallback auth mechanism if onetap isnt supported or not displayed.